# jQuery slider - change amount of next / last image shown

Tags: jquery, image, slider

I'm using the Nivo slider (http://nivo.dev7studios.com) which works perfectly fine for showing one image, but I'm trying to show half of the previous image and half of the next image. I'm open to using others like Slides or the Coin one.

Does anyone have ANY idea how to go about this?

The closest functionality I've found is this: http://webdesignandsuch.com/posts/fancymoves/index.html

but, it's a bit flaky and not the best to work with.

I've tried modifying the CSS to lower the size of each panel as well as adjust the positioning via absolute positioning, but I'm having no luck. It's been two weeks I've been working on this.

Somebody, please, help!

Comment: How about using HTML5 canvas? :) That is if you don't mind using modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

[MovingBoxes](http://chriscoyier.github.com/MovingBoxes/) is similar to the other plugin you posted. You can set the `panelWidth` variable to adjust the width (percent of total width) of the center panel.

Or [jCarouselLite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/jquery/jcarousellite/#demo) can show fractions of panels (click on "Fraction Configuration").

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

http://www.paulwelsh.info/jquery-plugins/hero-carousel/

The width of the div can be adjusted to your resolution.
Hope it helps you.